# Is SAXParserFactory susceptible to XXE attacks?

Tags: java, sax, saxparser, xxe

We read our XML template files using javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory. If there is XXE in the XML file we're reading, is there a way to turn off processing that?

thanks - dave

Comment: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XML_External_Entity_(XXE)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#JAXP_DocumentBuilderFactory.2C_SAXParserFactory_and_DOM4J

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is by default susceptible to XXE attacks.

Consult [this cheat sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XML_External_Entity_(XXE)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) for properly configuring the parser:

To summarize, you'll want to configure the relevant vulnerabilities with SAXParserFactory.setFeature(foo, bar) [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/SAXParserFactory.html)